# local php code works wrong in php based theme in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm super new with php/wordpress (first day today) and I trying to deploy application on my local machine (Windows 7/ 64bit's if that's matter). SO I get the sources - which is like a theme, deploy wordpress locally with xampp, and put my source folder to wp-content/themes

So now it works, but work's wrong. Some element's like header menu do not render, some text missed. And when I trying to do some navigation like `localsite/register` it realod the same page, but make page title "page not found", but `register.php` in the folder. This is work the same for any other pages except `login`. When hit `localsite/login` it redirect's me to `wp-login.php`

I do not need to change it somehow, just make local version looks and works the same as live. Does anyone have an idea why could that be and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: you must search some php and after it wordpress tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your pages do not executes because you do not create it like pages in CMS. That's also the reason why local version could looks different from the server one.

So you need to login to remote server admin panel and replicate all stuff from live server with the same way on your local server. I mean add pages, articles, configure menus, widgets, etc. And then your local version will be look and feel the same.